# Adding packages from different SVN repositories in a single project

Tags: svn

I am trying to create a project whose source code comes from 2 different SVN repositories. When I do the `svn co pathToRepoA currentDirectory` to checkout all the code from the 1st repo, it runs fine. Now, when I try to checkout some specific packages from the 2nd repo by doing

`svn co pathToRepoB/src/main/java/somespecificpackage currentDirectory/src/main/java/nameOfNewPackage`

into the same project, it gives me an error that the current directory is already a working directory of a different URL (which is an obvious error). How do I overcome this problem so that I can integrate code (some specific packages) from different repositories into a single project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)